# How can I include a service worker js file from src/ directory in index.html Angular 2

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm attempting to set up a service worker for a PWA in Angular 2. I currently have the service-worker.js file in src/assets/js and I'm able to include that in index.html with the following:

```
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/js/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
  });
}
</script>
```

The problem with this is that I get the error

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request for http://localhost:4200/assets/js/src/index.html?_sw-precache=5bad745861375765f6cd0b9440666847 returned a response with status 404`

Which is to be expected as index.html isn't located at /assets/js/src. If I try moving the service-worker.js file to src/ I get a 404 error on the js file itself because I'm guessing the Angular 2 dev server isn't picking it up? Does anyone know a way around this?

Edit: I'm using angular-cli

Comment: Are you using @angular/cli?

Comment: @yurzui yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `service-worker.js` file to `src/` and change angular cli config

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "service-worker.js" <==== add this
      ],
```